# Find JavaScript Code Integrate Clarifai Face Detection API

Tags: javascript, input, clarifai

taking a course where we integrate Clarifai Face Detection API into our app and the course shows a section on Clarifai's documents where you can copy some JavaScript code under what looks like "Request" and it has

```
app.models.predict(Model ID, Web Address)
    function(response) {
    },
    function(err) {
    }
);
```

Which is then used under our onSubmitRequest input. Any tips on where to find this?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

we generally don't recommend using this JS package as it is no longer supported  [[R]](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-javascript). Please use the NodeJS gRPC variant: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clarifai-nodejs-grpc or call our REST API directly: https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images (see "Javascript (REST)" code snippets)

Comment: Thanks - if I want to use the Face Detection API in my React app, how would I go about implementing the code you've listed above. I'm fairly new to this. In addition, I know I need my authentication key. Where do I find the Model ID for the face detection? https://www.clarifai.com/models/ai-face-detection

Answer (score 0):

I think that we just took the same online course and in order to accomplish that step, you will need to update your code basis according to the new Clarifai standards. I did that and it worked as follows:

Note:

- You will need to modify the USER_ID, PAT and APP_ID with your own credentials.
- Also, you will be using the result variable insted of the response variable.

In case you run into error or have any dubts check these links:
https://help.clarifai.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408131912727-How-do-I-find-my-user-id-app-id-and-PAT-
https://help.clarifai.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500007677141-Where-to-find-your-Model-IDs-and-Model-Version-IDs

```
onButtomSubmit = () => {

  //help me => user_id can be found in multiple ways, one way is in https://portal.clarifai.com/settings/profile 
  const USER_ID = "Use-your-ID-here";

  
  // Your PAT (Personal Access Token) can be found in the portal under Authentification
  // help me => PAT can be found in https://portal.clarifai.com/settings/authentication (create one if necessary!)
  const PAT = "Use-your-APi-Here"; 
  
  
  // help me => App Id is just the name of your app on the portal. 
  const APP_ID = "Use-your-app-name-here"; 


  // Change these to whatever model and image input you want to use
  // help me => https://help.clarifai.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500007677141-Where-to-find-your-Model-IDs-and-Model-Version-IDs
  const MODEL_ID = "face-detection";
  const MODEL_VERSION_ID = "45fb9a671625463fa646c3523a3087d5";

  const IMAGE_URL = this.state.input;

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // YOU DO NOT NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE TO RUN THIS EXAMPLE
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const raw = JSON.stringify({
    user_app_id: {
      user_id: USER_ID,
      app_id: APP_ID,
    },
    inputs: [
      {
        data: {
          image: {
            url: IMAGE_URL,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: "Key " + PAT,
    },
    body: raw,
  };

  fetch(
    "https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" +
      MODEL_ID +
      "/versions/" +
      MODEL_VERSION_ID +
      "/outputs",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) =>
      console.log(result)
    )
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
};
```

have fun :)